# Angular + Leaflet + Leaflet AwesomeMarkers - "Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angular, configuration, leaflet

I am trying to use [leaflet Awesome Markers](https://github.com/lvoogdt/Leaflet.awesome-markers) in my Angular10 project to use font-awesome icons in my standard leaflet markers. However, I am encountering the following error when trying to create a `L.AwesomeMarker`.

[image]

At the same time I am not receiving any import errors or similar during compilation with ng serve or in VScode.
The code in question that causes the error:

```
// leaflet-map.component.ts
import * as L from "node_modules/leaflet";
import * as awesome from "node_modules/leaflet.awesome-markers";

...

export class LeafletMapComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit{

...
  createDefaultMarker(mapMarker: MapMarker): Marker{
    const awesomeIcon = this.fontAwesomeIcon(mapMarker.icon, mapMarker.color);

    return L.marker([mapMarker.latitude, mapMarker.longitude], {icon: awesomeIcon})
      .bindPopup(this.getPopupText(mapMarker))
      .bindTooltip(mapMarker.location_details.name);
  }

  fontAwesomeIcon(){
    return L.AwesomeMarkers.icon({ //This is leaflet-map.component.ts:70
      icon: 'diamond',
      markerColor: 'blue'
    })
  }
```

They are definitely in the project at least, as they are listed under "dependencies" in my `package.json` file. Leaflet itself already works, it's just this plugin that's causing problems.

I am not entirely sure what's going wrong here, so I already tried the following:

- Including the leaflet and leaflet-awesome-marker js and css directly in the `index.html` of my project.
- Importing leaflet and leaflet-awesome-marker from a variety of different folders
- Including leaflet and leaflet-awesome-marker js and css in my angular.json file
- Importing awesome markers with `import * as L from "node_modules/leaflet.awesome-markers"` while not importing leaflet

None of it changed the error, likely because none of it fixes the issue that I'm importing something wrongly in my leaflet-map.copmonent.ts typescript. What do I need to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have abandoned to solve this type of problem myself. I instead opted to go for an alternative approach, write some custom CSS classes and a little bit of HTML, based on [this tutorial.](https://www.geoapify.com/create-custom-map-marker-icon/). I took the CSS classes 1:1 and put them into the `styles.css` file

**styles.scss**

```
.marker-pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: #c30b82;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
}
// to draw white circle
.marker-pin::after {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
 }

// to align icon
.custom-div-icon i {
   position: absolute;
   width: 22px;
   font-size: 22px;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: 10px auto;
   text-align: center;
}
```

**mapmarker.ts + leaflet-map.component.ts**

```
  //mapmarker.ts
export interface MapMarker{
    color?: string,
    icon?: string,
    latitude: number,
    longitude: number,
}

  //leaflet-map.component.ts
  createAwesomeMarker(mapMarker: MapMarker): Marker{
    return L.marker(
      [mapMarker.latitude, mapMarker.longitude], 
      {icon: this.divIcon(mapMarker.color, mapMarker.icon)}
    );
  }

  divIcon(icon: string, color: string){
    const markerIcon = L.divIcon({
      className: 'custom-div-icon',
      html: `<div style='background-color:${color};' class='marker-pin'></div><i class='fa fa-${icon} awesome'>`,
      iconSize: [30, 42],
      iconAnchor: [15, 42],
      color: color
    });

    return markerIcon;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What *may* happen is that the Leaflet.awesome-markers script is actually not imported / is tree-shaked out of your app, because the build engine sees that you do not use the declared import.

So instead of:

```js
import * as awesome from "node_modules/leaflet.awesome-markers";
```

You can try:

```js
import "node_modules/leaflet.awesome-markers";
```

By not declaring anything specific to be imported, you request that the script is imported unconditionally and avoid any tree-shaking optimization.

This plugin only performs the side effect of adding `AwesomeMarkers` key on global `L`, so there is nothing specific to import, besides running it.

Comment: That is a pretty fair suggestion and hopefully anyone running into the same issue gives this a try! Sadly in the meantime the project changed enough that I can actually no longer recreate the circumstances under which this happened. All I get are disappearing markers, which I recall didn't happen before. Might be that some resources are loaded differently to before.